# Time format in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, timestamp

I have a 2 columns. One with a planned time of departure and another with actual time of departure. Up until a few days ago, if there was a delay, the difference would read as a negative number. For example, if the planned time was 8:00AM and the actual time was 8:21AM, the 3rd column showed a delay as "-00:21:00"), but now the duration of the delay is displayed as 24:00:00 minus the number of minutes of the delay, as shown in this snippet:

[image]

Fortunately, any/all formulas still read and process the values, so this is really just a cosmetic issue for anyone who wants to glance at the raw data.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also share a copy of the file and include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Answer (score 2):

sounds like the formatting got reset. select your Delayed column and change the format to **Duration**

Comment: That was it! I was not aware that 'duration' was a formatting option. Thanks!